# QProcess with CreateNoWindow

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5.7

In C# there is an attribute which enables application to run 3rd party apps without showing the app window.

Is there any way to run a console application without showing the console window in QT without using Win32 CreateProcess function?

Answer (score 0):

`QProcess.start()` will run the console application without showing its window, but you may also wish to have some control over it. Please see this example:

```
QProcess p;
p.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
p.setStandardOutputFile("out.txt");
p.start("cmd.exe", QStringList()<<"/C"<<"ping"<<"127.0.0.1");
p.waitForStarted();
p.waitForFinished();
```

You can pass commands and parameters to the console using second argument in the start method (inside `QStringList`). It is also possible to redirect the output to some file, with `setStandardOutputFile` method.

If you need to show the window, use `p.startDetached()`.

Comment: so i will need the QThread if i want to use ping  x.x.x.x -t ?

Comment: @KooroshGhorbani sorry, your question is unclear, what are you trying to achieve? Which console application you are going to run?